# Replace string with PHP if statement

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have a API which outputs property (real estate) data from a central database into my website. I want to replace the names of some property types, with my own names. I have this code:

```
<?php echo isset($property['ROLType']) ? $property['ROLType'] : (isset($property['PropertyType']['NameType']) ? $property['PropertyType']['NameType'] : '-'); ?>
```

This category has many names/types of properties in it. One of them is "Detached Villa" which i would like to change to just "Villa".

I have tried with this, but no luck:

```
<?php echo isset($property['ROLType']) ? $property['ROLType'] : (isset($property['PropertyType']['NameType']) ? $property['PropertyType']['NameType'] : '-'); ?>

<?php
if(isset($wprow_details['Property']['ROLType'])){
if($wprow_details['Property']['ROLType'] == 'Detached Villa'){
echo 'Villa';
}?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: trim the data maybe it has space `trim($wprow_details['Property']['ROLType'])`

Comment: I thought of this, but would only work for this category as the names are similar. I need a way to change into whatever, as i will be renaming more categories, where original string and desired string, are totally different words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($wprow_details['Property']['ROLType'])){
        if($wprow_details['Property']['ROLType'] == 'Detached Villa'){
            echo 'Villa';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Serghei. Hmm did not work for me - no search results/properties are being loaded into my page now, so something must be wrong with the way i did it.

Comment: Sorry i forgot end bracket try now, it should work. I edit  my response

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me here. This time properties load, but no changes on the frontend. Still reads "Detached Villa".